# Open window 1 then close open window 2 then close

Tags: javascript, html, window

Ok i have this script it opens desired page then closes at desired amount of time.
How do i make it redirect to something rather than google.com when closing

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Page</title>
<style>
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#" id="target">Start Earning Points</a>; You will will <b>1</b> point per <b>1</b> view.</p>
<script>
(function() {
document.getElementById("target").onclick = function() {
var wnd = window.open("http://google.com");
setTimeout(function() {
wnd.close();
}, 15000);
return false;
};
})();
</script>
<script src="/js/render/edit.js"></script>
<script>var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-1656750-13'],['_trackPageview']];(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)})(document,'script')</script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, now the window will not close, it will redirect to yahoo.com. Hope this is what you are looking.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Page</title>
<style>
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#" id="target">Start Earning Points</a>; You will will <b>1</b> point per <b>1</b> view.</p>
<script>
(function() {
document.getElementById("target").onclick = function() {
var wnd = window.open("http://google.com");
setTimeout(function() {
wnd.location.href = "http://yahoo.com";
//wnd.close();
}, 15000);
return false;
};
})();
</script>
<script src="/js/render/edit.js"></script>
<script>var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-1656750-13'],['_trackPageview']];(function(d,t)
{var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)})(document,'script')</script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: This was actually exactly what i was looking for. Thank you, alot! I really appreciate it.

Comment: There will be a tick mark on the left-top of my solution just below the down arrow. Just click the tick mark, not the down arrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i am not clear what you are asking.
If you are asking to redirect after a particular time then you should modify your script like the following way :

```
   <script>
      (function() {
        document.getElementById("target").onclick = function() {
        var wnd = window.open("http://google.com");
        setTimeout(function() {
        wnd.location = 'http://yahoo.com';
       }, 1500);
       return false;
     };
    })();
   </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: @RyanHippensteel : Why are you smiling ?